# Attempting to send binary data through $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, content-type

I tried to post some binary data using jQuery's `ajax()` method. The problem is that the data `128` is encoded to string `"128"` (not `0xf0`) in the request body.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  type: "post",
  data: 128,
  contentType: "application/octet-stream",
  processData: false,
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Must the request body (i.e., the byte after HTTP headers) consist of only ASCII characters?

I'm confused about HTTP concepts such content type and transfer encoding. What I saw is most content is encoded to ASCII characters whether they are originally text or binary (such as image bytes are base64 encoded). The content type `application/octet-stream` seems to allow the binary data included in the request body, but how to explain the above example?

Comment: Yes, the body should be ASCII. If you want to send binary data use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), although you'll have much bigger issues actually creating binary information in JS. For what reason would you ever need this?

Comment: I know I can post string or json but if http specification does not prohibit binary data in http body, why not just send the raw binary data in the request?

Comment: You absolutely can, it's just that JS is *really* not built to handle binary data well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass a type that can handle binary data well, like `Uint8Arrayar`

```
var x = new Uint8Array(1);
x[0]=128;
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  type: "post",
  data: x,
  contentType: "application/octet-stream",
  processData: false,
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, using Uint8Array can send binary data. But I'm curious about the internal mechanism. Since I set processData=false to let it not encode the integer, why does not it put the binary in the request? Is there some reason on this?

Comment: Well, both xhr and fetch do not take a number as a request body, so it will either be rejected or converted to something that is acceptable so I guess it converts it to a string.  https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method